# How to setup PPPOE connection in CentOS

Tags: centos, pppoe

I want to configure PPPOE connection in the CentOS. I have selected the network type as DSL and interface `eth0`. But it is still not working. Please, any one tell me the solution to this.

Comment: I doubt that any one is able to help with with such little information available. Try following some tutorial to setup PPPOE connection on CentOS and add here both tutorial and what issues you face with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not notice, there is a **[Deployment Guide](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-network-config-xdsl.html)** on Establishing an xDSL Connection in the official centOS web itself. This should help you to achieve what you need.